# pandoc.exe out of memory when using profvis

Tags: r, shiny, profiling

I was simply trying to use the library profvis to profile a R Shiny App and got the error message below:

```
profvis({runApp("path_to_app", display.mode = "normal")})

pandoc.exe: Out of memory
Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\profiles-cache\file8fc51d02a3c.html --from markdown --output C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\profiles-cache\file8fc51d02a3c.html --self-contained --template C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpIFCFG7\file8fc61fe2472.html' had status 251
```

I heard there's a 2GB memory limit on Windows, and I'm just wondering if there's a way of getting around this. Thanks.